# Open IE and read page for IE 7 or newer c#

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, .net-4.0, automation

I need to open a browser (Internet Explorer 7 or above) for a given URL and then read the contents once it has finished loading. leaving the browser open for the user to use as normal afterwards.

Then I need to replace the page (if still open) with a new URL later if needed and read that page...

As I'm needing to leave them in IE after I have read the page I assume I can't use the browser control, so how would I do this?

This is a windows classic forms app using .Net4.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. Look http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/AutomateShellWindow.aspx

Once you have access to `IWebBrowser2` you can do everything you need, including navigate, read content etc.